# Generate the block with two ifconfig condition in layout xml

Tags: magento2, layout, ifconfig

I prepared a code which masks the phone field. Since on some of our customer's website the customer does not enter input for phone field on register page, i need to put second condition to render this block apart from the "module enabled flag"

On customer_address_edit page the phone field is always required but on register page it is optional.

What is the best practice to do that ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

Try this

```
<div class="field telephone">
            <label for="telephone" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone') ?>" type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
```